# I am getting duplicate Insertion in a database table from delayed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, locking, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I have the validation at code level that checks whether record needs to be inserted or not. ( Or to put in terms of business logic -- give user
 a badge or not).

So, there is a code at application_controller (runs on every request) that updates user's last_seen_at value and consecutive visits. To update these values I am running the following method in a `delayed job` before every request.
On every Nth consecutive visits to a site, I give user a badge. But few users have duplicate badges.

```
def set_last_seen_at
  time = Time.current
  if last_seen_at.present? && last_seen_at.to_date == time.to_date
    update_columns(last_seen_at: time)
  elsif last_seen_at.present? && ((time.to_date - last_seen_at.to_date).to_i == 1)
    visits = consecutive_visits + 1
    update_columns(last_seen_at: time, consecutive_visits: visits)
    if (visits % 7).zero?
      add_badge('Weekly User')
    elsif (visits % 30).zero?
      add_badge('Monthly User')
    end
  else
    # if last seen is unset or last seen is greater than 1 day
    update_columns(last_seen_at: time, consecutive_visits: 1)
  end
end
```

My Application controller:

```
before_action :set_last_seen_at, if: -> { current_user.present? && (current_user.last_seen_at.nil? || current_user.last_seen_at < 5.minutes.ago || current_user.last_seen_at.to_date != Time.zone.today) }

def set_last_seen_at
  DelayedJobThatRunsSetLastSeenAtForUser.perform_later(current_user.id)
end
```

From the above code,  user should get a `Weekly User` badge, If the last value in consecutive visits was 6 and the day has been past. This works Ok, But As I was going through the database there are few users who have duplicate entries of `Weekly User` badge and the created at for duplicate records is same (with difference in milliseconds). I am not exactly sure of this behavior and would appreciate any help in this regard.

Few Pointers:

1) I cannot add the duplicate check at database level as Users can  have duplicate badges. e.g: They can get multiple `Weekly User` badge.

2)  I am running the delayed job at background from systemd service with `rake jobs:work` . (not sure if this helps but I found this unique in my case). Since the above code is running in delayed job, shouldn't it be running in a single process and thread ?

3)  Is there anything I can do to ensure and test this kind of behavior. The only proof that I have of duplicate entries is from database record.

Comment: "runs on every request" sounds like it will produce some race conditions if the user does more than one request in a really short time and validations / counts / checks may return unexpected results.

Comment: Yeah, I do have the condition that adds the delayed job only if `last_seen_at < 5.minutes.ago` but I think it may still run the code in case of  multiple requests.

I am open to alternatives though.  I have also added my relevant application controller code, if it helps

Comment: @arieljuod, Shouldnt delayed job be running that method in a single process ?

Comment: One idea I can think is to save some timestamp on the session hash when you enque a job and check that timestamp before enequieng a new one. session hash will be updates a lot faster than the user's last_seen_at value that you are comparing. I'm not sure it will prevent this problem on any case, but it should reduce it a lot.

Comment: My intention is to stop it completely and be sure of that 100%.  Also,  to find the reason on why it would be happening ?

Comment: I don't know if that fixes the problem on any case because I'm just guessing it's a race condition and I don't know everything on the system, maybe you try that and you don't see any repeated badge anymore. Maybe it work on 100% of the cases, maybe it doesn't, but you have to try something if you can't find the specific cause of the problem with analysis (race conditions are really hard to properly reproduce to be sure to begin with). It's great to be 100% sure of something, but sometimes you can't be when something depends on the users you can't control.

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod for help, Sure yep  gonna try something with either redis or session hash.  Will update here on results